# Is Magento 2.1.13 version support MySQL 5.7 version?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, aws

Currently, my magneto project (2.1.13) connect with the 5.6 MySQL version in the AWS server.AWS server automatically will update MySQL version from 5.6 to 5.7 because MySQL 5.6 is deprecating in august.

So I need to clarify magneto 2.1.13 support to MySQL 5.7 version.

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-mysql.html this site mentioned as below

```
Magento 2.1.2 and later versions are compatible with MySQL 5.7.x;
```

hope you have some work experience with Magento 2.1 version with MySQL 5.7 version.

Please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Magento application **version 2.1.2** and later are compatible with **MySQL 5.7**.

check below links

**System requirements - M2.1**

http://www.www888.org/documentation/magento_doc/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

**System requirements - M2 latest**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html